# What is the best library for building an IRC bot in Java?

Tags: java, irc

In particular, I'm trying to find a library that provides an elegant way to deal with the event-based nature of IRC, without producing spaghetti code (as a naive event-based implementation often becomes).

Comment: Don't you like http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php? Which is first link that comes out of Google and they say they are the most popular :).

Comment: Been trying it, its my default option - but I find that its event-based approach is likely to lead to spagetti code unless I do a lot of work on a good framework (much as Servlets benefit from a framework like Apache Wicket).

My hope is that someone else has already solved that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) is an event-driven IO framework you might want to look at.

Answer (score 1):

[irc-api](https://code.google.com/p/irc-api/), a well designed Java IRC API that offers some features other IRC APIs don't (like asynchronous commands).  Main features are:

- State(ful/less) API
- Callbacks support / Asynchronous
- Message Listeners - Message Filters
- SSL implementation
- DCC implementation
- SLF4J/Maven integration

You might wanna give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I've already written such framework you mention in comment:

**[JawaBot 2.x](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/)** is a pluggable standalone application with IRC and web UI which aims to put multiple functionalities under one bot, while still keeping the structure of the code sane. **Mavenized**.
Currently, there are few plugins:

- Jira - resolves name, status and assignee from a Jira issue tracker. Configurable. Default config supports opensource repos: JBoss, Codehaus, Apache and others.
- Logger - logs IRC events to a DB. Has a web UI.
- Reservation - for reservation of resources over IRC. Has a web UI.
- WhereIs - looks for nicks in all channels, supports wildcards.
- Messenger - delivers messages to users which are offline when they connect ("answering machine").
- PasteBin - let's user paste text through PM, saves it, and posts a link to a web UI to the channel.
- AutoOp - gives op to users.
- Social - reacts to "Hi!" etc. Kind of [Hello World plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/wiki/HowToWriteIrcPlugin).

If you're not into that, you may try PircBotX which tries to fix PircBot's wrong design.

List of other options is also here: [Building an IRC bot in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750422/building-an-irc-bot-in-java)